# How to capture Test Case ID that's current being run in the MTM in C# test method

Tags: microsoft-test-manager, visual-studio-test-runner

How to capture Current Test Case ID that's current being run in the MTM pragmatically using C# code?

Thanks & Regards,

woodson

Answer (score 1):

Had the same question and found the answer: [how-to-retrieve-the-id-of-the-workitem-that-started-an-automated-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995330/how-to-retrieve-the-id-of-the-workitem-that-started-an-automated-test/18272068#18272068)

Basically you get it from the `TestContext` with `string tcId = TestContext.Properties["__Tfs_TestCaseId__"].ToString();`