# How to retrieve the ID of the workitem that started an automated test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, automated-tests

**Introduction:**
In VS2012, we have a set of workitems that are planned to be automated. I created a set of automated tests through SpecFlow in VS2010. To connect a workitem with an automated test, I have to select the workitem and search for the automated test that can only be exactly one method.

The drawback is that with a large amount of TestMethods (and we have), the list is very long. It will be a tedious task to connect a WorkItem with the corresponding TestMethod. Thereby, lots of our tests (and therefore the TestMethod names) are generated automatically because we use SpecFlow. And when a teammember change the name of the scenario, this TestMethod name is also changed, breaking the connection between the WorkItem and the automated test.

**What I want:**
I want to create a single TestMethod that can be selected for each automated workitem. This TestMethod retrieves the workitem ID and searches for a TestMethod that starts with that ID, or has a SpecFlow Tag attribute with that ID. Therefore I need the ID of the workitem.

**Question:**
How do I retrieve the ID of the workitem that initiated the test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution for retrieving the test case ID for a workitem in TFS for tests that are executed by Microsoft Test Manager:

```
string tcId = TestContext.Properties["__Tfs_TestCaseId__"].ToString();
```

Provided that this method is in a `TestClass` object. A `TestClass` object automatically gets a `TestContext` instance. MTM is using the `TestContext` to serve information to the `TestMethod` it is running.

A full list of the (undocumented) properties can be found on [the blog of InfoSupport](http://blogs.infosupport.com/switching-browser-in-codedui-or-selenium-tests-based-on-mtm-configuration/).

Comment: This is a LIFESAVER for us... Don't have enough up-votes for this :-) Thank you very much for supplying a solution here. All the potential workarounds are fragile and crap, quite frankly.

Comment: Anyway you could provide details on what you did in that single test method to search to tests that have the specflow tag of the workitem.  That would be really helpful to see!

Comment: @MarkLindell Unfortunately it didn't work out as I hoped for; I could retrieve the SpecFlow scenario and its mapped testmethod with the use of reflection, but you cannot just call that method. You must assign a testrunner that will run that specific method and I couldn't manage that yet. Because of shifting priorities and for the testers a sufficient work around I didn't put more effort in it to figure out how to get it running. Maybe later because I have another project with exact the same demands.